# OWL Carousel new product slider not showing up

Tags: magento-2.1

I have installed **Magento 2 Responsive Banner Slider and OWL Carousel by Welt Pixel** and I configured enabled it for **New products & last viewed products.**

[image][image]

Widget code was already placed but sliders are not displaying at front end

Comment: where you want to display ?

Comment: I already added the widget in to home page

Comment: How you are adding the widget in home page ?

Comment: content->pages->selecting homepage->insert widget.

Comment: {{widget type="WeltPixel\OwlCarouselSlider\Block\Slider\Products" products_type="new_products"}} ... inserted this code ?

Comment: {{widget type="WeltPixel\OwlCarouselSlider\Block\Slider\Products" products_type="new_products"}} exactly the same code

Comment: well surprisingly this is not working I just tested.. i find out the issue... till I am answering another way to display new products on home page .. try that way

Comment: yes,Is there any other extensions with documentation i'm new to magento..

Answer (score 2):

**Adding New Products Slider on Homepage Using Widget**

```
Admin > Content > Elements > Widgets > Add Widget
```

1 ) Select Welt-Pixel Product Slider and Theme

2) Give Title / Select Store View / Define Sort order

3 ) Select Slider from Widget options > New Products

4 ) Add layout where to Display

5 ) Display on specified page > CMS Home Page > After Page header

Try This way and check products are selected as new

I hope this will work , let me know if still not work

Comment: Again its not working..

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable Template Path Hints and check whether the widget has been added to the front-end or not.
2. If not, add. Then it works fine.